# Uso de funciones declaradas en Haskell

Tags: haskell

Se solicita resolver una ecuación matemática de la siguiente forma: x^2 + x*m + n, nómbrala como segundoGrado, por lo cual debe ser almacenada en una función que reciba como parámetros los argumentos necesarios para resolverla, como segundo paso deveras crear una función llamada "mulsegundoGrado" en la cual sumes el resultado obtenido de SegundoGrado de esta forma:

mulSegundoGrado = SegundoGrado + SegundoGrado.

RECOMENDACION: Usa estos nombres propuestos para las funciones para poder tener una mejor idea de como funciona el programa para su posterior análisis o re-estructura del mismo en caso de necesitarla, recuerda que mulSegundoGrado no recibe ningún parámetro, solo muestra el resultado

Pero tengo problemas al momento de poder resolver este ejercicio, debido a que separe las funciones en 2.

segundoGrado1 y segundoGrado2 para poder hacer la suma de ellas, pero tengo un error al momento de llamar a mulSegundoGrado, ya que al momento de ejercutar mis modulos me marca el siguiente error:

```
* No instance for (Num (a0 -> a0 -> a0 -> a0))
        arising from a use of `+'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In the expression: segundoGrado1 + segundoGrado2
      In an equation for `mulSegundoGrado':
          mulSegundoGrado = segundoGrado1 + segundoGrado2
  |
3 | mulSegundoGrado = segundoGrado1 + segundoGrado2
  |                                 ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Mi código de Haskell es el siguiente:

```
segundoGrado1 x m n= x^2 + x*m+n
segundoGrado2 x m n = x^2 + x*m+n
mulSegundoGrado = segundoGrado1 + segundoGrado2
```

Una alternativa fue hacer lo siguiente:

```
multiSegundoGrado x m n a b c= (x^2+x*m +n)+(a^2+a*b+c)
```

Funciona sin problemas, pero no va con lo solicitado del ejercicio, la idea es hacerlo como si fuera Java por ejemplo, al momento de hacer una operación se guarde en una variable (segundoGrado1) y esta se sume con la (segundoGrado2) para así solo obtener el resultado de la suma de estas dos funciones

¿Alguna solución?. Lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Cuando se habla de _ecuación_ se entiende que hay que encontrar el valor de `x` que haga la ecuación cero. Una ecuación de segundo grado tendrá dos soluciones (en el caso general) y es posible que se refiera a ello cuando te pide _multiplicar las dos soluciones_. La verdad es que la redacción no se entiende nada.

Answer (score 0):

El problema surge cuando se aplica la función sin el uso de argumentos correctos. Haskell permite la omisión de argumentos si lo omitimos la misma cantidad de derecha a izquierda (por ejemplo, son equivalentes `f x y = (g . h) x y` y `f = g . h`). Así que `mulSegundoGrado = segundoGrado1 + segundoGrado2` es posible solo si `segundoGrado1` y `segundoGrado2` son constantes (en este caso números). Debes plantearte en dónde quieres agregar los valores.

Una solución podría ser usando expresiones lambdas:

```
segundoGrado x m n = x^2 + m*x + n
mulSegundoGrado = \x m n y a b -> (segundoGrado x m n + segundoGrado y a b)
```